# IE9 (Standards Mode) Div height jumps on hover

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, hover

We have a project page here to check the issue live -> http://hdev.hattrick12.com/

Hovering the Post Elements causes the post height to jump in IE9/Standard for a split second.

It has something to do with *.post footer li* being display inline - but I need to have the elements either floating or display inline which both seems to cause trouble in IE9.

Can someone point me in the right direction as I can't find anything written on that specific IE Bug?

Comment: I don't get any posts in IE9, console says: `[WebSocket] cannot connect to Web Socket server at ws://hattrick12.com:80/socket.io/1/flashsocket/0864541222564 (SecurityError)
make sure the server is running and Flash socket policy file is correctly placed`

Comment: goddamnit, angular! I guess you brought me to another question..

Comment: Does it work on hdev.hattrick12.com/ for you?

Comment: Jup that works, but I don't have the described problem, everything's fine...

Comment: So when you hover the posts in IE9 they don't "jump" in height for a split second?

Comment: Nope, can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Does the problem occur both when logged in and when logged out? If there's some script or rule that applies only for logged in users that would explain the problems in reproducing the problem.

Comment: No, it happens for both - but I just resolved it :)

Answer (score 0):

I found it! It's the min-height of the elements that causes them to switch height for a split second when hovered.

Thx to everyone contributing